# Why am I getting a 'fatal: SASL library initialization'

Tags: postfix, mac-osx, sasl, smtpd

If I turn on smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes <- yes

I get this set of warnings and a fatal for SASL. 
I can not see why it's also looking for cyrus - which is not compiled in.

```
postfix/smtp[87056]: warning: unsupported SASL client implementation: cyrus
Apr 20 13:29:52 zeus.quantum-radio.net postfix/smtp[87056]: fatal: SASL library initialization
Apr 20 13:29:53 zeus.quantum-radio.net postfix/master[86038]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 87056 exit status 1
Apr 20 13:29:53 zeus.quantum-radio.net postfix/master[86038]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
```

My configs are like this:

```
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/testServer.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/System/Library/OpenSSL/private/testServer.key
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_sender_access  hash:/usr/local/cutedge/postfix/etc/access, check_client_access hash:/usr/local/cutedge/postfix/etc/access, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access hash:/usr/local/cutedge/postfix/etc/access
broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes

smtp_sasl_auth_enable=no
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/usr/local/cutedge/postfix/etc/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noplaintext,noanonymous
smtp_use_tls=yes

smtpd_helo_required=yes
```

Comment: did you realize that there is also the line `smtp_sasl_auth_enable=no` in your config? What you changed, was `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes`, which is not what you say in your question

Comment: yes, I know. It was yes - generated error - I changed it to no - error gone.

Answer (score 2):

[Postfix does not implement SASL itself](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html), but instead uses existing implementations as building blocks. Currently postfix only support two SASL implementation, Cyrus SASL and Dovecot SASL.

1. Cyrus SASL provide SASL framework for **both** Postfix SMTP server [smtpd](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html)  and SMTP client [smtp](http://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html)
2. Current implementation of Dovecot SASL [does not provide client functionality](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl).

So, that's clear enough why postfix **smtp** throws error about missing cyrus SASL implementation. It's because Postfix SMTP client only using Cyrus SASL implementation to get working.

---

The obvious solution is compile postfix with both SASL implementation: Cyrus SASL and Dovecot SASL. To check if they are both compiled to postfix use, [postconf command](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html)

```
postconf -a
```

Comment: Thanks, I have Dovecot - not Cyrus. I don't need client - smtp, so didn't compile it in. So I probably also need to turn off smtp_use_tls=yes

Comment: Good... That's will turn off the error.

Comment: I now have Postfix-3.1+Dovecot+Cyrus+Mysql+Pche compiled in and running - with Dovecot still the master. It seems to be working, mail is flowing - but now still getting "no worthy mechs found" in syslog. See other thread.